# Should I use transform instead of redraw?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have several charts I do redraw everytime I zoom/pann using d3 brushes.

But, when I have tons of rendered elements, redrawing starts to be a little bit slow.

Instead of redrawing all elements everytime I move my brush, I was wondering whether or not it's feasible to transform (translate) the already drawn elements, and only redraw whenever I need to update my data.

I think it would increase my visualization performance a lot whenever panning to right/left, wouldn't it ?

Any insights ?

Comment: Yes, this is possible and yes, it might increase performance. The only way to see if it actually does is to try it.

Comment: sure @LarsKotthoff, but I do have to deal with tons of different elements at once and prototyping it first would not be so fast. btw, I did prototype with only 1 chart and it is as fast as redrawing (my real problem is with a lot of elements at once).

Answer (score 1):

In general, the less you touch the DOM the better your performance will be.  The details are browser and platform specific, but in general this is the pecking order of performance at a very high level (ordered from most expensive to least):

1. Creating and removing DOM elements.
2. Modifying properties of existing DOM elements.
3. In memory JavaScript (that is, not involving DOM at all... e.g. Array iteration).

So if you can get the result you want by simply modifying a targeted subset of existing elements with a transform attribute, I would guess you will be much better off.

Of course, it's impossible to say anything with certainty without seeing the actual code and use case.

Comment: Thank you @Scott Cameron. I do appreciate your answer but I was wondering a D3 more specific answers, once brush element will be used and I'll need to deal with resize (zoom) and move(pann) within element attributes. I am performing some tests and debugs now and hopefully will have a better overview about it later :). thank you very much for your time.

Comment: The DOM operations are almost always the limiting factor in performance.  In my experience, it's rare that D3 itself shows up as being significant because it falls into the "in memory JavaScript" category. Of course, there are ways of using D3 that result in more or fewer DOM operations.  If you run the CPU profiling tools in Chrome it will help you figure out your hot spots.  IE9 actually has a surprisingly good profiler also that sometimes shows even better output than Chrome (probably due to less JS optimization internally).

Comment: I'm not sure if I agree that not touching the DOM will improve performance. In particular if you have lots of elements, simply rendering them might well be the bottleneck.

Comment: I agree, but I was assuming that the initial rendering had already been done because the original post was talking about a redraw.  My suggestion is based on incremental changes after the initial render is completed.  Another way to say it is that the initial render is the ultimate DOM operation (equivalent to adding all elements at once) and, as such, is (relatively) very expensive.